# Gremlin - if multiple vertices return multiple values each, how to limit the result to one per vertex

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

Essentially, I'm trying to modify the following piece of Gremlin code such that instead of operating on a single vertex at a time - signified by `g.V(1)`, it will work with multiple vertices at once (e.g. changing to `g.V()`), while still only limiting the number of returned results *per vertex* to **one** (see `limit(1)`).

```
g.V(1).repeat(out().simplePath()).until(has('color', 'red')).path().limit(1)
```

The above query will compute the shortest path from a given vertex to the closest vertex which has `property(color)==red`.

However, I want to compute the shortest path for multiple vertices passed in at the same time, while still only returning a single path per vertex.

I'm having difficulty modifying this without returning multiple paths for the same vertex however.

Comment: The reason I want to adapt this to work with multiple vertices is that I've ported it to work with the `gremlinpython` wrapper, and I want to minimize the number of queries to the gremlin-server, as each query can be time expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deduplicating the result by the start vertex should give you the expected result.

```
g.V().as('a').
  repeat(out().simplePath()).
    until(has('color', 'red')).
  dedup('a').
  path()
```

Example using the modern toy graph:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   repeat(out().simplePath()).
......2>     until(hasLabel('software')).
......3>   path()
==>[v[1],v[3]]
==>[v[1],v[4],v[5]]
==>[v[1],v[4],v[3]]
==>[v[4],v[5]]
==>[v[4],v[3]]
==>[v[6],v[3]]
gremlin> g.V().as('a').
......1>   repeat(out().simplePath()).
......2>     until(hasLabel('software')).
......3>   dedup('a').path()
==>[v[1],v[3]]
==>[v[4],v[5]]
==>[v[6],v[3]]
```